# in case you update a member of a set in c++, does the set automatically change the order?

Tags: c++, set

I want to use a set `S` of type `node` and I want to manipulate the cost section in the set and order the set by `cost`:

```
 struct node
 {
     int label;
     long cost=LONG_MAX;
     bool visited=false;
     bool operator < (const node &other) const { return cost < other.cost; }
 }

set<node> S;

//here i just want to update the cost of a node in my set S

set<node>::iterator it=S.find(vertex);
*it.cost=200;
```

Does that change the order in the set automatically?

Comment: Set elements are immutable, since the set structure depends on the *value* of the elements (because a set is an *associative* container). So you cannot change elements in a set.

Answer (score 7):

> Does that change the order in the set automatically?

Not only does it not change the order of the `set`, but the operation itself is illegal. Associative container iterators give you a `const` type for the key - so `*it` in your example has type `node const`.

If you think about it, that's the only way to ensure the invariant that the container provides. After all, how could `it->cost = 200` possibly update the underlying `set`? Maybe if C++ had reflection and the iterators dereferenced to some proxy that had overloaded `operator=` that... yeah that just sounds like a mess.

The current idiomatic way to "update" an element in a `set` involves erasing it, modifying it, and then re-inserting it. In your case:

```
auto it = S.find(vertex);
node cur = std::move(*it);
auto next = S.erase(it);
cur.cost = 200;
S.insert(next, cur);
```

That's admittedly pretty tedious.

---

There is a proposal ([P0083R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0083r2.pdf)) to improve this in the future.

---

Update for C++17: that proposal has been accepted. Now you want to use [`extract()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/extract):

```
auto node = S.extract(vertex);
node.value().cost = 200;
S.insert(std::move(node));
```

This will avoid an extra copy of your type and an extra allocation/deallocation.

Comment: "improve" in efficiency, but not really verbosity.

Answer (score -4):

You cannot normally change the existing contents of the set. It's a dirty little secret, but `std::set` iterators are really `const_iterator`s. Go ahead and try to compile that, you'll get compilation errors.

Of course, there are ways around that, but they will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: Not really a "secret" if the compiler tells you about it..

Comment: Not really a "way around" if it isn't actually guaranteed to work.

Comment: `iterator` is a constant iterator for associative containers. That doesn't mean they're the same type, though.